# Icon in button not registering click event

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a button with text and a down-arrow icon, which I use to trigger a dropdown. When I click the text part of the button, the dropdown appears, and I have some jquery to amend the text and flip the arrow - great. But when I click the icon part of the button, the text changes and the icon flips but the dropdown doesn't appear.

Do I convert it to an anchor link and change the clickable area, or is there a more simple solution?

### HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info button-drop text-nowrap" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ph-detail" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ph-detail">See More 
<i class="bi bi-arrow-down"></i>
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="ph-detail">
<p>Expandable content</p>
</div>
```

### JQuery

```
$('.button-drop').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).html('See Less <i class="bi bi-arrow-up">');
  } else {
    $(this).html('See More <i class="bi bi-arrow-down">');
  }
});
```

Comment: Assuming your "drop down" works without the jquery here then issue is: when you click on the `i` the event is for the `i` but you're removing the `i` so there's no event anymore to bubble up to the parent button.  Change your jquery to change the class rather than the html of the button.  To change the text, put it in a span and change just the text, eg `$(this).toggleClass("bi-arrow-up bi-arrow-down").closest().find("span").text("See More")`

Comment: Thanks - the dropdown does indeed work without the query. I've lost you at the last part - can you expand the query a bit more?

Comment: Don't use `.html()` - instead include all the html you need then show/hide it as needed (ie two `<i>` tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it with the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info button-drop text-nowrap" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ph-detail" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ph-detail"><span>See More </span>
<i class="bi bi-arrow-down"></i>
</button>
```

```
$('.button-drop').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('bi bi-arrow-up');
    $(this).find('span').text(function(a, text) {
        return text === "See More " ? "See Less " : "See More ";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the code are working for me. I think you have not added the cdnjs file of jQuery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
$('.button-drop').click(function() {
  $(".button-drop").toggleClass( "active" );
  if ($(".button-drop").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".button-drop").html('See Less <i class="bi bi-arrow-up">');
    } else {
      $(".button-drop").html('See More <i class="bi bi-arrow-down">');
    }
});
```

```js
$('.button-drop').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).html('See Less <i class="bi bi-arrow-up">');
    } else {
      $(this).html('See More <i class="bi bi-arrow-down">');
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you click on the icon itself

Comment: its working for me https://codepen.io/alexios_leonidas/pen/abmeNed

Answer (score 0):

So, I had something similar happening and it APPEARED that the onClick function was not being triggered, but it was, but there was an immediate state change after because of an event listener function that I had established to collapse my drop-down menu when clicking outside.

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches(".dropdown button")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.style.display === "block") {
        openDropdown.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This created a race condition and the style was updated to "none" immediately after being changed to "block". It's a bit different since I'm not using jQuery (just vanilla JS) but I think the concept is the same and may be the problem described by the OP.